# Android Intent.ACTION_SEND Hyperlink doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, hyperlink

I know there are hundreds of post related this question but I have been trying to put a hyperlink into my body but it is not working!!

For example, the below example I have found on this website which is posted a couple of months ago. [You can see the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631264/hyperlink-in-gmail-through-intent-action-send-android)

```
String link = "www.facebook.com"
String body_part = "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + link+ "</a>"

intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body_part ));
```

But in the body, there is only text content. There is no link.

Do you have any idea that why it is not working?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and got the solution just now. Make changes in your code as below and it'll work.

```
String link = "www.facebook.com";
String body_part = "<![CDATA[<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + link+ "</a>]]"
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body_part ));
```

Hope this helps you as well! :)